# `\multicolumn` did not produce correct output

Tags: tables, macros, longtable, line

I am using `\multicolumn` in the following code. But it is not producing proper output, please see the output attached.

Where is the problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etextools}% for entry
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\NewDocumentCommand\separateswarbol{m}{\StrBefore{#1}{)}[\swars] \StrBetween{#1}{[}{]}[\bols]}
\begin{document}
\separateswarbol{x,y,z,w)[a,b,c,d]}
\readlist\bollist{\bols}%
\readlist\swarlist{\swars}%
\newcounter{swarstringlen}%
\newcounter{actualswarstringlen}%
\newcounter{bolstringlen}%
\newcounter{spos}%
\newcounter{bpos}%
\StrCount{\swars}{,}[\swarlen]%
\StrCount{\bols}{,}[\bollen]%
\setcounter{swarstringlen}{\swarlen}%
\setcounter{actualswarstringlen}{\swarlen}%
\addtocounter{actualswarstringlen}{1}%
\addtocounter{swarstringlen}{2}%
\setcounter{bolstringlen}{\bollen}%  
\stepcounter{bolstringlen}%
\stepcounter{bolstringlen}%
\setcounter{spos}{1}%
\setcounter{bpos}{1}%
\begin{longtable}{*{16}c}%
\whileboolexpr%
{test{\ifnumcomp{\value{spos}}{<}{\value{swarstringlen}}}}%
{\ifnum\value{spos}=\value{actualswarstringlen}\uppercase{&}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\swarlist[\thespos]}\addtocounter{spos}{1}\else\uppercase{&}\multicolumn{1}{c}{\swarlist[\thespos]}\stepcounter{spos}\fi%
}\\
\whileboolexpr%
{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{bpos}}{<}{\value{bolstringlen}}}}%
{\ifnum\value{bpos}=\value{actualswarstringlen}%
\uppercase{&}\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bollist[\thebpos]}\addtocounter{bpos}{1} %
\else \uppercase{&}\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bollist[\thebpos]}\stepcounter{bpos}\fi%
}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's the hack of using, in the relevant cells, `\multicolumn{c|}{...}`, for instance.

Comment: @Bernard I'm sure you meant to say "documented interface", not "hack" :-)

Comment: @Bernard I tried `\multicolumn` but the verticle lines are not matching, they appear at different positions.

Comment: Could you please post a (complete) code of what you've tried?

Comment: if you use `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}` (if your column preamble is `c` for that column) then the rule will be in the same position for every row where you use that. It is always best to include a complete small document so people can use the code in answers, you haven't even shown the full table.

Comment: wow where on earth did you get that from, it seems massively over complicated!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wrote it. ;-). This is a part of a bigger picture.

Comment: if you put x just before `\end longtable` you can see there is a cell there and your w entry is spanning two cells but I don't think I want to trace that code to work out why.

Comment: Thanks for the observation I will do the rest.